# How to extract common parts of UiBinder files?

Tags: java, gwt

Lets assume that we have two pages built with UiBinder. The UiBinder file can be similar to this:

> ```
> <g:HTMLPanel>
>     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.login}">
>         <g:FlowPanel styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.majorLoginBox}">
>             <g:FlowPanel styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.loginTop}"/>
>             <g:FlowPanel styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.loginContent}">
>                 <g:LazyPanel ui:field="inputPanel">
>                     <g:FlowPanel styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.loginForm}" addStyleNames="{style.resetPasswordForm}">
>                         <g:Label text="{localization.forgotpassword_form_header}"
>                                  styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.loginFormHeader}"/>
>                         <g:Label text="{localization.login_username}"/>
>                         <g:TextBox ui:field="username" inputMaxLength="64"/>
>                         <g:Label ui:field="validationError" styleName="{resourceBundle.css.errorText}"/>
>                         <g:Anchor ui:field="sendButton" text="{localization.forgotpassword_send}"
>                                   styleName="{resourceBundle.loginCss.loginButton}"/>
>                     </g:FlowPanel>
>                 </g:LazyPanel>
>                 <g:LazyPanel ui:field="messagePanel" visible="false">
>                     <g:Label ui:field="messageLabel"/>
>                 </g:LazyPanel>
>             </g:FlowPanel>
>         </g:FlowPanel>
>     </g:FlowPanel>
> </g:HTMLPanel>
> ```

In general it doesn't matter what is there, just an example. And of course there are two java classes which correspond to these UiBinder files. So, it is quite obvious that from java classes I could extract common parts to some abstract class.

*Is it possible to do it for UiBinder files? How?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common part can be a [Composite widget](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html#composite) with its own UiBinder file. Then you can simply insert this widget into other UiBinder files. For example, if `w` points to your widget library:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    ...
    <w:MyWidget>
    ...
</g:HTMLPanel>
```